# Why the privatekey is different between BKS and PEM

Tags: java, android, keytool

I want to get privatekey from BKS store by program but i found it is difference between my parse and the pem file.

Any body know why is that?

Here is my code:

```
KeyStore testkeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("bks");
testkeyStore.load(inputstream, keystorepass);
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)testkeyStore .getKey("xxxxx",keypassword);
byte[] bas = key.getEncoded();
bas = Base64.encode(bas, Base64.DEFAULT);
String keys = new String(bas);
Log.d("XXX","keys " + keys);
```

Here is how i transfer bks to pem:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore xxx.bks -srcstoretype BKS -destkeystore xx.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

openssl pkcs12 -in xxx.p12 -out xxx.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer after i traced code of openssl project.
The private key was encrypted, here is the code:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/pkcs12.c

[image]